# How to translate the URL with router enhancer

Tags: typo3, router, extbase

I have a customized extbase extension, which shows different contents based on the parameter.

```
class SiteController extends ActionController {
   /**
    * @param int $year
    */
    protected function newsAction(int $year) {
        ......
    }
}
```

And here is my routeEnhancers in the config.yaml.

```
routeEnhancers:
  News:
    type: Extbase  
    limitToPages: [6]
    extension: Site  
    plugin: Pi1  
    routes:
      - routePath: '/{year}',
        _controller: 'Site:news'
```

However, it doesn't convert the URL `http://landing.io/news?tx_site_pi1[year]=2018&cHash=f1a79b262f6567570dd78b6148b17554` to `http://landing.io/news/2018`, but I can visit `http://landing.io/news/2018?cHash=f1a79b262f6567570dd78b6148b17554`. So, I guess I missed something.

Could anyone help?

Comment: How do you generate the link? Is it typolink or is it a form?

Comment: I use <f:uri.page> and <f:uri.action> generally.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, fix a typo in the config.yaml, it should be `Site::news` instead of `Site:news`.

After some debug, I finally solved this question.

According to the [Routing Enhancers and Aspects](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.5/Feature-86365-RoutingEnhancersAndAspects.html), it's said

> When creating extbase plugins, it is very common to have multiple controller/action combinations. The Extbase Plugin Enhancer is therefore an extension to the regular Plugin Enhancer, providing the functionality that multiple variants are generated, typically built on the amount of controller/action pairs.

in the Extbase Plugin Enhancer section.

However, if you want to have the extbase routing enhancers to work, you **MUST** have `&tx_ext_pi1[controller]=CONTROLLER&tx_ext_pi1[action]=ACTION` in your URLs, which is all the URLs do in the section but I didn't realize. Otherwise, you will get `FALSE` in `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Routing\ExtbasePluginEnhancer::verifyRequiredParameters()` and never get your URLs translated. So, I think this point should be included in the doc, or at least highlight the last sentence starting from "typically".

Meanwhile, there is also a TypoScript setting in the EXT:extbase, called `config.tx_extbase.features.skipDefaultArguments` or `plugin.tx_ext.features.skipDefaultArguments`, which will remove the controller and/or action arguments if they are equal to the default controller/action of the target plugin. If it's enabled, it will also break the routing enhancers for the same reason. Unfortunately, I enabled this since very beginning to make the URLs short.

There is another setting, `config.tx_extbase.mvc.callDefaultActionIfActionCantBeResolved`, you may need to be care about, which might cause the same problem.

Anyway, the new routing feature is pretty great.

Comment: You can give a defaultController: to your Extbase route enhancer. I think that would solve your problem, too. https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Routing/AdvancedRoutingConfiguration.html